# SELECT statement inner join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find out if I can make one query to out of three I have now.

```
 $sql     = "SELECT * 
             FROM joblist WHERE customer = :customer"; // this is a bindParam 

 $sql_val = "SELECT a.customer, SUM(a.value) AS tvalue
             FROM joblist AS a
             INNER JOIN joblist AS b
             ON a.customer = b.customer
             GROUP BY a.customer";

 $sql_bal = "SELECT *
             FROM (SELECT SUM(balance) AS tbalance 
             FROM joblist GROUP BY customer) AS total_balance
             WHERE tbalance = :tbalance";
```

The table that I am using is customer and following is are the columns.

```
ID - work_order - customer - description - value - balance - status - notes
```

I'm using php PDO and HTMl of course.

Basically, I have a search function used to query a company. The result are displayed, but I need the totals for the value and balance columns. The only thing that really works is pulling in the data from the table. I've had no success at getting the totals for value and balance.

[Current code page](https://pastebin.com/39ykv0kv)

Comment: Explain exactly what you're expecting by joining the queries and the issue you're getting by combining three queries.

Comment: i can't understand your question.please make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not understand your question well so I'll make some guess:

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  t2.tvalue,
  t3.tbalance
FROM
  (SELECT
    *
  FROM
    joblist
  WHERE customer = :customer) t1
  JOIN
    (SELECT
      a.customer,
      SUM(a.value) AS tvalue
    FROM
      joblist AS a
    GROUP BY a.customer) t2
    ON t1.customer = t2.customer
  JOIN
    (SELECT
      b.customer,
      SUM(b.balance) AS tbalance
    FROM
      joblist AS b
    GROUP BY b.customer
    HAVING tbalance = :tbalance) t3
    ON t3.customer = t1.customer;
```

Comment: cackekai, that's what I was looking for. Good grief I couldn't wrap my head around that. Haven't touched this stuff in like 10 years. Sorry for the confusion about the question guys/girls. I know I wasn't explaining myself quite right as my google results didn't yield that I needed or was wanting to do. Thanks very much!

Comment: ok new issue.. lol lost my php array.. how would I get the array back from the join statement ?